# RemotingException was unhandled "Attempted to call a method declared on type 'System.IFormattable' on an object which exposes 'HES.MyProcess'."

Tags: c#-4.0, remoting

i started to work with .net remoting, read myself through tutorials and explanations, saw now at least three examples on the web and they looked all similar to my code. i can't find the reason for the error I get. (RemotingException was unhandled "Attempted to call a method declared on type 'System.IFormattable' on an object which exposes 'HES.MyProcess'.")
I tried to fix this for six hours now, unsuccessfully looking up the internet, reading through lots of pages...
Maybe you guys can help me out ?

MarshalByRefObject deriving class looks like:

```
public class MyProcess : MarshalByRefObject, IMyProcess
{
    //public System.Diagnostics.Process process {get; set;}

    public MyProcess()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
      //  this.process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    }

    public string GetProcessId()
    { Console.WriteLine("I'm on..");
    return "test";
     //  return this.process.Id;
    }
}
```

My interface loooks like this:

```
interface IMyProcess
{

     string GetProcessId();

}
```

My server looks like this:

```
namespace HES
{
public class HES_Starter
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

        // using TCP protocol
        TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(_port);
        //second value is for security settings
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
        Console.WriteLine("HES Server here... on PID: " +    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);

        //Type, objectUri to access the object remotely, mode
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
          typeof(HES.MyProcess), "HESProcess",
          WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);


        Console.ReadLine();
}
}
}
```

and finally my client like that:

```
namespace Service_Provider
{
public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

        TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel();
        //second value is for security settings
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

        Console.WriteLine("HES Client here...");

        IMyProcess remoteProcess = (IMyProcess)Activator.GetObject(
                typeof(IMyProcess), "tcp://localhost:8050/HESProcess");


        Console.WriteLine(remoteProcess);
        Console.WriteLine(remoteProcess.GetProcessId());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

does anybody have a clue what i'm doing wrong ?
I mean from the exception I can see that the client knows that the object is an remote object in the 'HES' namespace. And in debug I can see that the object

```
remoteProcess = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}
```

is a proxy...
I don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried taking out the `Console.WriteLine(remoteProcess);` line? My guess is that that's causing the problem.

Comment: hm, yeah thanks, I can't remember why I put it in...
    Console.WriteLine(remoteProcess);
was on my way finding an different error ...

Comment: now I get this error:
    Cannot load type 'Service Provider.IProcess, Service Provider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
and I think that was the reason why Iput the console.writeline in the code. Do you know what this error means ?

Comment: Solved !
Thanks to @Jon !

Remaining problem solved here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522847/cannot-load-type-error-net-remoting

Comment: Do you want me to look into why that line caused that problem, or is it not particularly relevant to you now?

Comment: @Jon No thanks, everything wokrs fine now - thanks to you!
I accidently put this line into my code - trying to solve another problem and got this error I mentioned in this thread.
I was so sure that the error came from the remoting elements, that I just focused on that and forget to check the rest of the code.
I missed the forest for the trees...